# Connect to AD with Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory

Does Sharepoint have the possibility to display right information in the Sharepoint's website to the user from Active Directory by using Sharepoint as a middleman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. SharePoint uses the User Profile Service Application to sync the profile database in SharePoint to your AD. You can set up which properties are mapped and pulled through if you select your user profile service application from Central admin service applications and configure it all there.